# How to apply a single class to multiple elements in CKEDITor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Situation

I have several classes that can be used across multiple elements.  For example

GrayTopper should apply as a to an h1, h2, h3 or p tag

I want my HTML output to be 
 or  
or even  ...

I"ve tried t follow along with some solutions that suggest, but this appears to break the styles dropdown.  Is there a way to accomplish?

```js
                    name : 'Orange Button',
                    element : ['p', 'a']
                    attributes :
                    {
                            'class' : 'btnOrange'

                    }
            },
```

Comment: You want to color odd or even elements like in table rows, is that it ?

Comment: No,  I want to be able to apply the same class to an h1 or h2 or h3 or p